# Datetime convert to string in object of class

Tags: php, class, datetime, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I know there are a lot open topics for this question but I wasn't able to find any solution.

I am trying to get my object of class from entity in symfony via getter and I have trouble getting datetime field because it can not be converted to string.

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$get->getBirthDate(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)),
```

I think this is proper way but it does not work.

This code works:

```
$get->getBirthDate = $date->format('Y-m-d'),
```

but

> object of class declared dynamically

Comment: If you are using a **getter** `getBirthDate` then surely that method should be returning a field from your DB So no parameter in that call is required, or would make any sense

Comment: To create DateTime object with format like this `$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01')`. Static `::createFromFormat` creating from string with given patter  `DateTime` object.